# Using the attribute selector with Jquery but results dont work fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in my script:

```
function setup_buttons() {
    $('#showdiv_Home').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    });
    $('#showdiv_About_Overview').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    });
}
```

This is the selection in the HTML:

```
<li><a href="" id="showdiv_Home">| HOME |</a></li>
<li><a href="" id="showdiv_About_Overview">| ABOUT US |</a>
```

and this is the div's it needs to show and hide:

```
<!-- This is the front page -->
<div id="div1" style="display:block">
    <p> I am div 1</p>
</div>

<!-- This is the About-Company overview page -->
<div id ="div2" style="display:none;">
    <p> I am div 2</p>
</div>
```

I cant see anything wrong with the code but I need some of you smart people to help me out here.

When I click on my selection in changes the div display to block but only for a second and then changes itself back to hide. I cant figure out why.

Really, my question is, how do I fix it?

Comment: you've not called the function.

Comment: um, a fiddle would help, especially since you've already formatted the code nicely ;)

Comment: why are you using setup_buttons ? I think you mistakenly placed??? remove that and see if that works...

Comment: @ Nepal, I have called the function to be ready further up. I havent copied my entire code on here. Not enough room. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the href's value of anchor tag to "#". it will work for you.

```
 <li><a href="#" id="showdiv_Home">| HOME |</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="showdiv_About_Overview">| ABOUT US |</a>
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R697u/)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Would you have the time or share with me a link as to why the href="#" was giving me problems?

Comment: If you keep it blank it tends to refresh the page. I don't have any links right now. I got this while I was stuck on the same issue. Also the '#' in href will bump the page to top. instead you would like to use 'javascript:void(0)'

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showdiv_Home').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    });

    $('#showdiv_About_Overview').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not put the `click` events in the function like that, just do this in doc ready block:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('div[id^="div"]').hide();
    $('#div' + idx).show();
});
```

### [Demo with shortest way possible.](http://jsfiddle.net/cUWNq/)

Answer (score 0):

you can s use this code...

```
function setup_buttons()
        {
            $('#showdiv_Home').click( function()
                {
                    $('#div2').hide();
                    $('#div1').show();

                });
                $('#showdiv_About_Overview').click( function()
                {
                    $('#div1').hide();
                    $('#div2").show();

                });

        }
```